# How do I filter through an array of objects and have that value match a value of another array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show pictures depending on the category that is associated with the object. There is an array of objects and each object contains a category key. There is a separate array called categories. I want to be able to click on one of the values from the categories array and have it show all the objects that have same category key.

The values in the categories array are dynamically created.

I am able to show both the categories array as well as map through the array of objects and get all the objects. I am not sure how I would connect both of them though.

Here is an image of what I have so far:

[image: a busy cat]

This shows all the saved images with all the categories.

I want to be able to click a category like change, and only get objects associated with that category.

Images.js

```
const Images = props => {
  let { images } = props;
  const categoriesView = () => {
    if (images !== [] && images !== undefined) {
      return (
        <div>
          {images.map(img => {
            let { id, link, category } = img;
            console.log('category', category)
            return (
              <div key={id}>
                <Image saved="true" cats={link} alt="icons" />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
  return <div>{categoriesView()}</div>;
};
```

Category.js

```
const Category = () => {
      return (
        <ul>
          {categories.map(category => {
            return (
                <li 
                  onClick={props.click}
                  value={category}
                  key={category}
                >
                  {category}
                </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      );
  };
```

Comment: Your example is not very clear. A code sample in codepen would help though.

Comment: Hi Lee, just wrote you an answer, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have better success doing something like this. Have a higher-order-component like Categories, feed the selectedCategory to the Images component.

**Categories.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Images from "./Images";

class Categories extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: ["sleeping", "eating", "standing"],
    selectedCategory: ""
  };

  selectCategory = category => {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedCategory: category
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.selectedCategory)
    );
  };
  render() {
    const categories = this.state.categories;
    const selectedCategory = this.state.selectedCategory;
    return (
      <div>
        {categories.map(category => {
          return (
            <div onClick={() => this.selectCategory(category)}>{category}</div>
          );
        })}
        <Images category={this.state.selectedCategory} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Categories;
```

**Images.js**

```
import React from "react";

const catPictures = [
  {
    id: 1,
    link:
      "https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gray-and-white-cat-asleep-with-whiskers-out.jpg",
    category: "sleeping"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    link: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MVV_HXtEbLo/hqdefault.jpg",
    category: "standing"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    link:
      "https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cat-eating-plate-shutterstock_92543212.jpg",
    category: "eating"
  }
];

const Images = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {catPictures
        .filter(cat => cat.category == props.category)
        .map(cat => (
          <img src={cat.link} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

Here is the sandbox as well:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ovp06w562q

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I passed my props done and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome @Lee! Glad this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Images component does not know which category is currently selected. Pass in the currently selected category that gets updated by the onClick method in Category component and then use conditionals to check if **category** variable within your map is same as the category that is passed as a prop to Image Component.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
      {images.map(img => {
        let { id, link, category } = img;
        category === 'category'
        ? return (
            <div key={id}>
              <Image saved="true" cats={link} alt="icons" />
            </div>
        )
        : null
      })}
    </div>
```

you can do it this way. map through all the images and only display the ones that match that category.